# How to make 2 (Double) Ring Custom Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-progressbar

Single progress bar is quite old fashioned. I am trying to make a double ring 
 circular progress bar.

I have been adding two shapes inside the XML code by it gives error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="0"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:toDegrees="360">
     <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
        android:thicknessRatio="4" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />

           <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#396338"
            android:endColor="#00FF00"
            android:angle="0" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Current progress bar:

[image]

But I want to make something like this:

[image]

Comment: you could use a custom view and draw two rect's by calculating the progressing with start angle and sweep angle with paint of your choice. there are lot of custom progress bar libraries available on github from where you can grab the logic and implement it yourself.

Comment: Well i am using Xamarin Android , Finding Projects and Logic Related To Xamarin Android is Quite Difficult nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use two progressbar where outer progressbar's value can be used by inner progressbar simultaneously